# GLMM: relationship between AIC, R squared and overdispersion?

Tags: lme4-nlme, aic, glmm, ecology, overdispersion

First of all, I am a beginner in statistics, and I have been reading some questions and comments here regarding this matter but I am still a bit lost.

My problem:
I am constructing GLMM's in order to assess habitat selection. For now I am doing some exploratory analysis to each one of my variables. I am checking AIC (and AICc, which has been the same for AIC) and R squared (both using `MuMIn` `R` package), and overdispersion, using `RVAideMemoire` `R` package. I am a beginner in statistics, and I have been reading some questions and comments here regarding this matter but I am still a bit lost.

Regaring the dataset:

X is the dependent variable, it is binomial (1 and 0); 1 represents "used" locations, obtained through telemetry techniques, and 0 represents "available", which are random points collected across each study area. Variable A represents study areas and Variable B represents interactions between individuals (represented in codes, for instance: M01-M02; M01-M02-F01, and so on), and each group of individuals is unique for each study area. Variable 1 represents a given type of land cover.

```
str(data1)
'data.frame':   32670 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ VarA: Factor w/ 5 levels
 $ VarB: Factor w/ 51 levels 
 $ X      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Var1     : num  -0.201 -0.201 -0.201 -0.201 -0.201 ...
 $ Var2     : num  1.383 -0.973 -0.748 1.611 -0.973 ...
 $ Var3     : num  -0.0985 -0.0985 -0.0985 -0.0985 -0.0985 ...
 $ Var4     : num  -0.482 -0.482 0.942 -0.482 -0.482 ...
 $ Var5     : num  -0.502 0.293 0.813 -0.783 2.41 ...
```

For each variable, I am constructing a GLMM using two different random effects, because I don't know which one is best/most appropriate for my data.
For instance, I have these models for the same variable:

```
    lm1 <- glmer(x~Var1+(1|VarA), data=data1, family = binomial(link="logit"))
    lm1_1 <- glmer(x~Var1+(1|VarA/VarB), data=data1, family = binomial(link="logit"))
    lm1_2 <- glmer(x~Var1+(1|VarA)+(1|VarA/VarB), data=data1, family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

For each model, I check AIC, R squared and overdispersion, and I don't know how to interpretate my results. For instance:

lm1: AIC-19908.9; overdispersion-0.609;r2m and r2c almost zero (4.06e-07)

lm1_1: AIC-8806.5; overdispersion-0.261;r2m-0.0016 and r2c-0.7923

For lm1_2 I get:

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00174688 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

ANOVA for lm1 and lm1_1:

```
> anova(lm1, lm1_1)
Data: data1
Models:
lm1: Used ~ Var1 + (1 | VarA)
lm1_1: Used ~ Var1 + (1 | VarA/VarB)
        Df     AIC     BIC  logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
lm1    3 19908.9 19934.1 -9951.4  19902.9                            
lm1_1  4  8806.5  8840.1 -4399.3   8798.5 11104      1  < 2.2e-16 ***
```

This pattern repeats itself across other variables.

1) How do I interpret this?
Because, if I focus only on AIC, lm1 is the most appropriate, and also if I consider overdispersion. But R2 is terrible. If I focus on R2, it is only good for lm1_1 and only for the nested random effect, which would indicate that the nested random effect is "correct". Am I right?

2) Are there any other good approaches for GLMM?

Comment: Can you provide more details about your data  - for instance what are `VarA` and `VarB` ? Normally the physical/biological situation would dictate whether or not to include higher levels of grouping. Trying to select a model based on a combination of AIC and psuedo $R^2$ is often futile as they are both difficult to apply to GLMMs and they are assessing different things. Also, note that `(1|VarA/VarB)` is equivalent to  ` (1 | VarA)+(1 | VarA:VarB) ` which will fit a random intercept for both `VarA` and `VarB` with `VarB` within `VarA` so the `(1|VarA)` in your formula for lm1_1 is redundant.

Comment: I am sorry, I had the formula for lm1_1 wrong, now it is update. I only considered for lm1_1 "(1|VarA/VarB)", that is why I was confused. When I used both, I got the message "model failed to converge" (updated as well).

Comment: Please can you also explain what X is and also how the data were collected.  Is each individual unique within each area ? Also please provide information about the dataset (total observations, total individuals, total areas) perhaps include a `str()` of the data.

Comment: It is updated now!!

Comment: Why are variables `Var2`-`Var5` not in the model ? Also, please post the output from `glmer()` for `lm1` and `lm1_1` along with the output from `anova(lm1,lm1_1)`

Comment: Because for now I was just looking into each variable alone. But I have included more and the result is usually the same (relatively), if I use one random effect or the other. By the output, you mean "summary()"?

Comment: Yes, I meant `summary()` - do you want to continue this in chat, which is better than lots and lots of comments ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41977/discussion-between-teresa-and-robert-long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only 5 levels of `VarA`, which is too low to use it as a random effect. This can lead to incorrect estimates and numerical problems. Since its estimated variance from the output that you provided in chat was `1.226e-08` this is another reason not to include it.

You have measured 4 other variables which are of importance in your study, apart from `Var1` so these should be included as covariates, subject to considerations of mediation and collinearity. You might consider including one or more of these as random slopes.

As for model selection, I think we have established that lm1_1 can be discarded, but if/when you have competing models it is not unusual to find contradiction from pseudo-$R^2$ and AIC. Since you have a large enough dataset you can do cross-validation, where you build your models on one subset of the data and assess their predictive abilities on a different subset.

Finally, overdispersion appears to be minimal and not a cause for concern.

Comment: I conducted some analyses with the same data and I had what seem to be weird results. I constructed a model with all variables (fixed/random effects), and then used "dredge()" to select the "best" models, according to AICc delta and weight. When I use VarB (ID), I obtain very low values for weight, but VarB as a random effect has  variance 13.02 (SD 3.6),which seems significant. But if I conduct the same test but with a "glm()" instead of "glmer", thus without the random effect, weight values are higher. What does it mean? Should I not use a random effect at all? Or is not related?

Comment: @Teresa, please ask a new question about this, giving as much information as possible.

Comment: done! here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222949/glmm-relationship-between-aicc-weight-and-random-effects

Answer (score 3):

Without any information on your data, it's difficult to help you properly. One thing that struck me is that in you 2nd model (lm1_1) you have 2 times the same random term: 1 time VarA is not nested and the 2nd time VarB is nested in VarA. I believe you'll have to decide which one to keep, is VarB nested in VarA (then only keep "+(1|VarA/VarB)" or is it not (then only keep "+(1|VarA)"). I can't think of a reason why you would have those 2 in your model.

If you are a beginner, you probably should spend some time reading and understanding how to build GLMM. I suggest you to follow the steps described in the book from Zuur et al. (2009) *[Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441927646)* to understand how do build a GLMM. I read it 2 times and it really helped me to understand GLMMs.

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference, the `(1|VarA)` in lm1_1 is simply redundant. +1 for the Zuur reference !

Comment: @RobertLong Good to know that `(1|VarA)` does not make a difference and is simply redundant. However, I would say that it's always good to keep your codes as simple as possible for clarity.

Comment: I updated my post, I wrote wrongly lm1_1, sorry, it only includes "(1|VarA/VarB)". When I include both, I get the message "model failed to converge".

Comment: Well, that's probably because of this redundant `(1|VarA)` term. But really, you should look into Zuur's book, GLMMs are complex beasts and I don't know how I would have navigated through this without the explanations provided in this book. I would also add that never in Zuur et al. book I remember them saying to base your best model on R2. If you don't have to add more explanatory variables, I would say that lm1_1 is the best so far (lowest AIC), your overdispersion is fine (lower than 1) and if individuals are nested within sites than it seems fine to me.

Comment: Is it ok if the overdispersion value is low, for instance, 0.2? Is there an interval of "best" values for this measure?

Comment: Lower it is, better it is. The cut-off value is 1, so if you're below this means your data are not overdispersed (which is good) if it's above 1 this means your data are overdispersed (which means you'll have to use quasibinomial instead of binomial).